# How to bind a shape's properties to a business model's properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a canvas that represents the user's display.
On the canvas you can draw- and resize rectangles that represent sections of the screen.

I have a model called Section. And my viewmodel has a collection of them.

I want to somehow bind- and auto create/update the `List<Section>` everytime a rectangle has been drawn- or updated (resized/deleted).

**My Section.cs looks like this.**

```
public class Section
    {
        public int SectionId { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public SectionType SectionType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Layout")]
        public int LayoutId { get; set; }   
        [ForeignKey("LayoutId")]
        public virtual Layout Layout { get; set; }
    }
```

So in effect I want the following happening:

**New section:**

- A user draws a rectangle on the canvas
- A new Section is created, and added to the List
- The Section gets the Width, Height, X, Y, etc. from the rectangle

**Existing section**

- A user selects a rectangle and resizes it
- The new Width, Height, X and Y are updated in the corresponding Section

I can't figure out how to bind a Rectangle to a Section so that they are linked. When the user selects a Rectangle that was created a while ago, the code should automagically know which Section to update.

Any pointers in the right direction on how to solve this with best practices is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ObservableCollection of Section type objects in your ViewModel.

```
ObservableCollection<Section> _col;
public ObservableCollection<Section> Sections
{
    get { return _col; }
    set
    {
        _col = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Sections");
    }
}
```

and Bind it in your XAML as following

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sections}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <Canvas Background="White" Width="500" Height="500"  />
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: That looks great. How do I access the Canvas though? In my old code, I had named my canvas and I have a bunch of code-behind event handlers for the drawing portion.

Comment: Canvas _canvas = itemsControl.ItemsPanel.LoadContent() as Canvas;